# How to append values to set() to the end in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, set

Have got a `item = set()`, need to append values to this '*item*' to the end. But *set()* append it to first position pushing already present values to last as shown below.

```
item = {'Mango'}
item.add('Apple')

#Returns
{'Apple','Mango'}

#Expected output
{'Mango','Apple'}
```

Even tried `item.update(['Apple'])` doesn't work.

Comment: `set` is not an ordered sequence

Comment: atleast is there any option to reverse the elements in the set()

Comment: Reversing would also imply order, which again sets do not have. If you care about "first" or "last" values, and not just whether or not the value is _in_ the set (which you haven't provided enough context to really say), it's the wrong data structure.

Comment: Sets have NO order

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a data structure that has an ordered sequence. You can do this with lists instead of a set, and use .append to add things to the end of the list:

```
item = ['Mango', 'Apple'] 
item.append('Pear') 

#Output
['Mango', 'Apple', 'Pear']
```